# Delegate functionality for different view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

This image http://postimg.org/image/3qo8x6lyv/

[image]

In AddContactViewController.m (for the blue one)

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self passBD];
}
- (void)passBD {
    //some code

    [self.delegate passDataBack:p];
}
```

`passDataBack` is declared in AddContactViewController.h and defined both in MasterViewController.m (for the grey one) and DetailViewController.m (for the yellow-ish). I tracded the program but I found that:

When I go from Master to AddContact view controller while returning back `viewWillDisappear` is executed which calls `passBD` which calls `passDataBack` defined in MasterViewController.

When I go from Detail to AddContact view controller while returning back `viewWillDisappear` is executed which calls `passBD` but it does not call `passDataBack` defined in DetailViewController.m

The trace just goes past it. When I command+click `passDataBack` it shows the three options Master, Detail and Add. Why from one VC its executing but from another it isn't?

**EDIT** DetailViewController.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"editContact"]){
        AddConatctViewController *passData = [segue destinationViewController];

    //some code
    }

}
```

**MasterViewController.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addContact"]){
        self.addContactVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        self.addContactVC.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
**AddContactViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PersonHolder.h" 
@protocol AddDataDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) passDataBack:(PersonHolder *)data;
@end
@interface AddConatctViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,weak) id <AddDataDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Comment: provide the code when you go master to addContact and Detail to addcontact...

Comment: And also the addContact .h file code

Comment: In DetailViewController set the delagate as self while instantiating AddConatctViewController i.e passdata.delegate = self

Comment: @RatikantaPatra ummm... ok but now I'm getting a weird error. But thanks.

Comment: don't worry I rectified it.

Comment: Ok keep it up @Rishab